# When to use % and when to not

Tags: comments

I have recently falled into an [error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272694/rows-of-the-same-column-behaves-differently-why/272702#272702) because I didn't use % when I was supposed to. My question is now: When do I have to use % at the end of the line and when should I leave it out?

Comment: Related Question: [When is it harmful to add percent character at end of lines in a \newcommand, or similar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34844/4301).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An end of line is a space so your question is asking when to add a space.

```
foo
bar
```

is the same as

```
foo bar
```

but

```
foo%
bar
```

is the same as

```
foobar
```

so it just depends on the context. Sometimes a space is needed to separate words, or for TeX syntactic reasons, sometimes a space is not needed but ignored anyway, and sometimes a space is definitely wrong at that point.

Comment: ...except for things like `verbatim`, where an EOL is not a space.

Comment: I also think it worth to explicitly mention that spaces (and thus `%`) are ignored after `\if` family of conditionals, as well as after `\else` and `\fi`...since they are used pervasively in macros.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes ??? `\if` has no special treatment of spaces.

Comment: Did I say that?  Must have been my alter-ego.  Need to adjust the meds.